# 500 ответ от стороннего сервера

Tags: node.js, express

Есть задача вытащить данные "Тип налогообложения" клиента зная его инн,
Нашел подобный ресурс.
https://pb.nalog.ru/search.html

есть функционал который позволяет получать нужные мне данные,
проверил через postman - работает, начал писать сервер под это дело.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const rp = require('request-promise');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post("/getTypeTaxing", (request, response) => {
const optionFirst = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://pb.nalog.ru/search-proc.json',
  headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  },
  body: {
      mode: 'quick',
      inn: `${request.body.inn}`,
      page: 1,
      pageSize: 10
    },
       json: true
    };


    rp(optionFirst)
    .then(body => {
       console.log(body)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

В результате постоянно 500 ответ, в не зависимости от типов данных + get запроса

Answer (score 1):

По вашему вопросу могу сказать следующее:

Во-первых, убедитесь, что вы точно эмулируете поведение пользователя, в некоторых случаях сервер может отклонять ответы без/либо с неверным:

**1. User Agent**

Проверяется, чтобы отсечь ботов. Также сервер может не выдавать ответ (выдавать предупреждение), если используем User Agent для устаревших браузеров. Например, на конец 2018 года практически все заголовки с MSIE6 идут от ботов.

**2. Accept Language**

Может вызывать ошибку на сервере, если там стоит автоматическая проверка на используемый язык и если сам код не обрабатывает ситуацию отсутствия/пустого заголовка.

**3. Cookies**

Даже если на сайте не выполнялась авторизация при AJAX-запросах может передаваться дополнительная информация из Cookies. Например, тот же XSRF-TOKEN. Надо смотреть что именно отправляется при запросе данных с сервера (для Chrome это Dev Panel -> Networks).

**4. X-Requested-With**

Этот заголовок может требоваться у AJAX-запросов, если на сервере стоит проверка на него.

Также могут быть дополнительные проверки на прочие заголовки Host, Accept и т.д.

Comment: перед публикацией всех этих предположений их можно было бы просто проверить `curl 'https://pb.nalog.ru/search-proc.json' --data 'mode=quick&page=1&pageSize=10&&query=Пупкин'`. А причина затруднения топикстартера совершенно проста - при таком наборе аргументов как у автора в запросе сервер сообщает ему, что `{"ERROR":"-","ERRORS":{"query":["Не заполнено обязательное поле \"Поисковый запрос\""]},"STATUS":400}`. Лечится это простым добавлением параметра query: `curl -X POST 'https://pb.nalog.ru/search-proc.json' --data 'mode=quick&page=1&pageSize=10&query=fff&inn=1234567'`